# tikz graphics slightly cropped

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,fill opacity=0]
\filldraw[fill=yellow] (0,0) circle (8cm);
\filldraw[fill=orange] (2,0) circle (6cm);
\filldraw[fill=red,line width=2pt] (-4,0) ellipse (4cm and 3cm);
\filldraw[fill=green] (0,0) circle (4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

I've added the yellow highlights to point out my question: how to prevent these portions of the curves from being clipped/cropped? It is even more noticeable the thicker the line width.

Edit:

I updated all my TeX-related packages (this was in MiKTeX 2.9 with PDF-LaTeX output viewed in Acrobat). Here is a close up of the PDF to show that it is indeed there:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting the crop. Is there any thing missing? Have you tried with some other viewer?

Comment: Are you using `standalone` or some form of `clip`ing?

Comment: Hmmm... Using MikTeX 2.9, PDF-LaTeXing and that is the output as viewed in Acrobat. I shall investigate further...

Comment: @HarishKumar: The missing part is just the highlighted parts are noticeably thinner than they should be. It shows up for me in all my viewers.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: No, I don't use either of those.

Comment: Does the clipping amount change if you remove the `thick` option from the picture?

Comment: @percusse: Removing the `thick` helps everywhere except on the portions on the ellipse. Removing `line width=2pt` and `thick` fixes everything, but in the end I need lines thicker than the default.

Comment: @JohnD -- I do get a cropped figure located on the right side of a page, with the code using MiKTeX and TeXworks. But after adding \usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}, everything seems OK.

Comment: Add me to the list of those with no thinning.  MikTex LaTex=>PDF and acrobat.

Comment: I cannot reproduce either. MikTeX, pdfLaTeX, Sumatrapdf. @JohnD, has this been resolved?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an non-reproducible issue.